# How to get pdf invoice programmatically

Tags: php, invoice, pdf

In Magento Backend, when looking at an invoice details, it is possible to get a pdf version in clicking the "print" button.

Is there a way to get this pdf invoice using a php script?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
```

where `$invoice` is the invoice object.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it logs me an error : Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/payment/info/pdf/default.phtml

Comment: Ok, so if you look at app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php, you will see a method called "toPdf" which sets the template for the info block. You dont need to change this, but rather copy the template to your theme folder. The template can be found in: "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/pdf/default.phtml". Copy that to your theme folder and re-test.

Comment: no more error but neither pdf….

Comment: Is my code right : https://paste.ofcode.org/sjZ3JbN7cKKp4raX9j3Ree